# Failed to install Ubuntu 12.10 on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: 12.10

Virtual Computer setup: 512 MB RAM

Laptop spec: 
i3 2.1Ghz
2GB DDR3 RAM
Nvidia GT525M

I am install ubuntu successfully just now, but the VM crash once it needed to be reboot. What can I do now?

Comment: Failed per se is not a good Question update your post  with this information What did you do? what step did you do? What guide are you follow? What error did you get? thx.

Answer (score 0):

After complete installation make sure you change the controller : IDE settings of the virtual machine in its settings Window under "storage" to "empty" again from the "bootable OS disk " you used to install your virtual OS.

Otherwise what happens is that on restart your virtual machine, your machine keeps booting from the disk .